# Redirecting WordPress profile page

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I've got a BBPress forum that generates a profile page like this: forum/profile/USERNAME.

What I want to do is use .htaccess or the Redirection plugin to redirect this link to /profile/USERNAME and cut out the profile part.

What's the best way to do this?

Cheers,

Ian

Comment: `and cut out the profile part...` The folder `/profile` from  `forum/profile/USERNAME`? Please explain.

Comment: I want it to redirect from sitename.com/forum/profile/username/ to just be sitename.com/profile/username/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/profile/([^/]+)/?  /profile/$1  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://sitename.com/forum/profile/username/`

To

`http://sitename.com/profile/username/`

String `username` is assumed to be dynamic while `forum` and `profile` are assumed to be fixed.

For permanent redirection, replace `[L,NC]` with `[R=301,L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the server respond with a 301 using RedirectMatch (part of mod_alias) in your .htaccess file:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/profile/(.*) /profile/$1
```

Comment: This is how I tried to do it, but it isn't working.  I'm wondering if BBPress has its own htaccess that is overriding the 301?